# Special link for Mobile Chrome to open page on Desktop Chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a website which is designed **uniquely for Desktop Chrome Browsers**. Not surprising, many of my users first arrive at my website through mobile browsing and I indeed detect that and display a dedicated message inviting them to open the link on their desktop Chrome Browser.

What i'm looking for is a special URL that, if clicked on a Mobile Chrome app, will send the page to the user's Desktop chrome to open in a new tab.

I saw that the new Chrome offers a way to [share pages between devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9430554?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1), given the user is logged in on both. However, that requires the user to click the "share" button on his mobile chrome, then click "share to device" and select their desktop device".

I'm looking for a way to construct a link that, when clicked, will do this automatically.

Comment: you can check view mode of browser and force the view to desktop

Comment: Forcing the view to desktop on a mobile won't work... the user actually needs to view my website on a desktop computer (there are interactions in place that work **only** with the **desktop** chrome browser)